# R package with private github dependency

Tags: r, github, package, devtools

I'm developing an internal R package which is going to be stored and installed from github, but it depends on another R package which is also in a private repo.

I know how to specify remote dependencies with the devtools `Remotes:` tag ([vignette](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/blob/master/vignettes/dependencies.Rmd)) and I know how to install private repositories using `install_github(source, PAT)`. But how do I do both? The idea is to have a server just install the package, and also install all of the dependencies on github.

Comment: Maybe create a private _repository_ instead of patching band-aid fixed around a perfectly working dependency mechanism?  We use public and private [drat](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/drat) repositories...

Comment: Store the pat in an environment variable `Sys.setenv(GITHUB_PAT = pat)` then devtools will automatically use it everywhere.

Comment: Oh, of course. So then I just specify the repository in `Remotes:` and it will install it normally.  Because it will call `install_github()` which in turn calls `github_pat()` to look in the environment variable. 

Do you want to make this an answer so that I can approve it?

Comment: Update, it seems like @Jeroen's approach should work, but there seems to be a devtools bug which hasn't yet been resolved: https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/1262

Answer (score 4):

Just putting @jeroen's response in answer format:

> Store the PAT in an environment variable Sys.setenv(GITHUB_PAT = PAT)
>   then devtools/remotes will automatically use it everywhere.

---

This works when the private repos all use the same PAT. I wonder how we'd do this for remotes with different PATs...

Comment: I know that this is an old thread, but just to be clear - I store the PAT in an `.Renviron` file at the root of my project. Do I add `.Renviron` to `.gitignore`, because obviously I don't want to push a PAT to a repository where it can be seen. Then I push my changes as usual and GitHub actions will use the PAT in my `.Renviron` when installing dependencies for CI and will thus download the private repository I have specified in the `Remotes:` section of my `DESCRIPTION` file?