# R packages in private organization - how to install private dependencies within organization?

Tags: r, github, github-actions

Our GitHub organization is private and is developing multiple private R packages within multiple different repositories in our organization. Some of these packages have dependencies on other repositories in our private organization. How can I set up GitHub actions to be able to install these private dependencies? My description file currently contains:

```
Imports:
    MyPackageDep
Remotes:
    MyOrg/MyPackageDep
```

The relevant portion of my GitHub Actions `.yaml` is:

```
  - name: Install dependencies
    run: |
      remotes::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE)
      remotes::install_cran("rcmdcheck")
    shell: Rscript {0}
```

I tried following the advice of [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39618746/r-package-with-private-github-dependency) by storing my PAT in an `.Renviron` file. But not only does this still not work, I still am not sure how this would work with multiple contributors to the package. Would they all just need to set up their own local `GITHUB_PAT` in their own `.Renviron`?

I also tried following the advice of this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/r-lib/actions/issues/208) by including the following in my GitHub workflow:

```
 env:
      GITHUB_PAT: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

The workflow still failed to download the dependency.

Is there anyway with GitHub Secrets to pre-configure the repository to have access to all other private repositories in an organization?

Comment: Have you had a look at this? 
https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/95 
They seem to be using it the way you need it to?

Answer (score 1):

The `GITHUB_TOKEN` only gives you access to the current repository. You need to generate a PAT and grant it access to your organization: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

Then add the PAT as a secret to your repository:

[image]

Then in your action yaml you can add:

```r
    env:
      # This allows installation of private github repos
      GITHUB_PAT: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
```

Then the r-lib/actions should be able to access the internal repos.